# Binding or delegating a property

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I need one class to modify the property of several other classes. So i need to somehow delegate or bind the property to the modifying class. This is a mockup of how the classes are organised.

```
MainClassA IHasAmount
        int Amount 
                Price
                        Goodstype
MainClassB IHasAmount
       int Amount
              Quality
                     Weight
IHasAmount
int Amount get; set;

AmountModifierClass
       IHasAmount HasAmount
```

This way Amount would be modified like this:

```
HasAmount.Amount -= AmountModifier();
```

Its just a tiny detail annoying me that the name gets redundant. I would like to be able to type it just as a property or field. So i try with this:

A)

```
int Amount=>  HasAmount.Amount
```

But that doesnt work because it becomes read only. So i assume that its not pointing too the original Amount property but its a getter, without a setter. So i try the following:

B)

```
 int Amount   { get { return HasAmount.Amount; } set { HasAmount.Amount = value; }}
```

And this works! I can now use a private property of the AmountModifier class that is bound to the Amount property of the MainClass like so
Health = HealthModifer

My question is if this is an efficient and not to complex of solving this situation? I guess what i need is to be able to bind one property to another in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

```
// This one indeed is a getter-only
int Amount => HasAmount.Amount;
```

and

```
int Amount { get => HasAmount.Amount; }
```

and

```
int Amount { get { return HasAmount.Amount; } }
```

Are just different ways to write the exact same thing.

---

So in your case your working solution

```
int Amount 
{ 
    get { return HasAmount.Amount; } 
    set { HasAmount.Amount = value; }
}
```

can also be written as

```
int Amount 
{ 
    get => HasAmount.Amount;
    set => HasAmount.Amount = value;
}
```

So if you don't want to expose the `HasAmount` reference this is a totally valid way of implementing such property and I don't see an issue with efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a property automatically delegate to another property using C# language only features.

The way I have accomplished this is by creating an object behind each property, so the property ends up looking roughly like this:

```
int Amount { get => GetPropertyValue(); set => SetPropertyValue( value ); }
```

The `GetPropertyValue()` and `SetPropertyValue()` methods receive the name of the property ("Amount") by using the `CallerMemberName` attribute.  Internally, they look-up a property object by name in a dictionary mapping names to property objects, and they get or set the value of that property object.

Then, delegation can be achieved as follows:

```
int AmountOfOtherObject 
{ 
    get => GetDelegatingPropertyValue( otherObject, nameof( otherObject.Amount ) ); 
    set => SetDelegatingPropertyValue( otherObject, nameof( otherObject.Amount ), value ); 
}
```

The `GetDelegatingPropertyValue()` and `SetDelegatingPropertyValue()` methods lookup a special kind of property in the same dictionary, which is a delegating property which delegates to the corresponding property of the "other" object.

It ends up being quite a bit more verbose than I wish it was, and it also requires substantial infrastructural support. If you try implementing this, be prepared for a deep dive down a long rabbit hole.

Comment: `There is no way to have a property automatically delegate to another property using C# language only features.` ... of course there is. As OP already said `int Amount   { get { return HasAmount.Amount; } set { HasAmount.Amount = value; }}` this is working

Comment: @derHugo true, if you just want plain properties. Unfortunately it stops working if you also need `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications. True, the OP did not ask about that.